# Can I reuse a pointer after reallocating memory it points to?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm new to C. I knew that when I use `realloc()`, the pointer is deactivated as the new block of memory may be in another address (is it set to null?). But a pointer just stores the value of an address. So can I reuse that pointer to store another address after that? Moreover, can I do this:

```
ptr= realloc(ptr, newsize);
```

Comment: do always a realloc to a temporary pointer so that you can recover if realloc returns NULL, otherwise you end up with a memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. It's nothing inherently wrong with it. However, it can make it impossible to recover from a failed allocation. If you're planning to exit the program if the allocation fails, it (usually) does not matter.

So this is perfectly fine:

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, newsize);
if(!ptr) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

And so is this:

```
tmpptr = realloc(ptr, newsize);
if(!tmpptr) puts("Allocation failed. Continuing anyway.");
else ptr = tmpptr;
```

Note: It can be argued if it's ok to exit with a memory leak. In most cases, that does not matter, since the operating system will usually clean everything up upon exit. So be aware that in the first example, you will exit with a memory leak.

So if a memory leak does matter to you, even if you're exiting on failure, you can do something like this:

```
tmpptr = realloc(ptr, newsize);
if(!tmpptr) {
    free(ptr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else {
    ptr = tmpptr; 
}
```

However, do notice that this would only solve the problem for the `ptr` pointer. If you have a program of any complexity above simple school assignments, chances are pretty high that you have a few other allocations already going on. Keeping track of all that is possible, but far from trivial. Consider this very minimalistic example:

```
void foo() {
    void *ptr1 = malloc(SIZE);
    if(!ptr1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    bar();
    free(ptr1);
}

void bar() {
    void *ptr2 = malloc(SIZE);         
    if(!ptr2) {
        // Here we should call free on ptr1 to avoid memory leaks, but how?
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Do work
    free(ptr2);
}
```

Of course, you could easily rewrite it:

```
void foo() {
    void *ptr1 = malloc(SIZE);
    if(!ptr1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if(!bar()) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    free(ptr1);
}

int bar() {
    void *ptr2 = malloc(SIZE);         
    if(!ptr2) return 0;
    // Do work
    free(ptr2);
    return 1;
}
```

In this case, it was easy, but keep in mind that this example is VERY trivial.

I would not bother unless I have a very good reason to care. It makes the code messy and is completely unnecessary on modern operating systems. Unless I'm writing code for an environment where it does matter, I would only care if I'm writing a function where I want it to be up to the caller to exit or not.

The bottom line here is that making sure that all allocated resources are freed by the program on exit can be a complete nightmare. And unless you have the need for it and are willing to spend quite a lot of time getting it right, then don't bother.

In practice, dealing with this would require you to take this into account for almost all aspects of the design. And that's very rarely a good tradeoff.

Related question: [dangers of _exit() - memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3720872/6699433)

Comment: its not perfectly fine since it creates a memory leak if realloc fails. your second example otoh is ok.

Comment: @AndersK But then it's a benign memory leak so klutt does make a good point.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse it but you should first check that the reallocation has succeeded.

If the reallocation failed, then after

```
ptr= realloc(ptr, newsize);
```

you've lost a reference to the old memory block, i.e., you have most likely created a memory leak.

What you probably want is:

```
void *newptr;
if ( (newptr=realloc(ptr,newsize)) ) ptr = newptr;
else /*handle the error*/;
```

Comment: Thanks. But in your example, you write `if (newptr)` . is not that wrong because the value in newptr is not 0 or 1? Do you mean `if (!newptr==null)`

Comment: @MohammedElbagoury `if (newptr)`, `if (newptr!=NULL)`, `if (newptr!=0)` all work. `if (X)` is generally equivalent to `if (X!=0)`: it works for booleans, integer types, and also for pointer types because the integer constant `0` doubles as both an integer and the null pointer constant (`NULL`).

Comment: @MohammedElbagoury If you want an explicit `NULL` in the code, then `if (!newptr==NULL)` isn't guaranteed to work. `!` binds tighter than `==`, so `!newptr==NULL` is `(!newptr)==NULL` which compares an integer (boolean 0 or 1) with `NULL`. `NULL` can be expanded to `0` in which case it will work, or it can expand to `((void*)0)` in which case you'll get a constraint violation (compiler error or warning). `NULL` is weird because of how it can be just `0`. Using an explicit `(void*)0` instead of it would be better.